# How to express the fact that one property occurs in one path before another property in CTL?

Tags: tree, logic, operator-keyword, computation, ctl

I would like to express the fact that there is a path where the "p" property occurs before the φ goal, in CTL as shown in the following figure.
[image]
For this I thought of the formula ∃(∃◇p U ∃◇φ ). Is this formula correct?